# Как отодвинуть линки навигационного меню направо

Tags: css, css3

Есть навигационное меню в котором линки расположены на левой стороне меню. Как отодвинуть линки направо, например, на 200px от левого края?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  /* text-align:center; */
  /*  margin:0 auto; */
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #000080;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 250px;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.submenu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

li:hover .submenu li {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Item2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

делаю как описано тут(http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/css/css-center-nav.php), первый метод но не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отодвинуть на `200px` от правого края Вам необходимо сделать так:

Добавить для главного списка меню свой класс, например, `.nav__main-menu` и добавить ему `css` свойства:

```
.nav__main-menu{
    margin: 0px 0 0 200px;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Как это выглядит:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 800px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 850px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  align-self: inherit;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li a:hover {
  background: #000080;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 250px;
}

.submenu li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.submenu li a {
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

li:hover .submenu li {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav__main-menu {
    margin: 0px 0 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul  class="nav__main-menu">
    <li><a href="">Main</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Item2</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item4</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
  <br />
  <form action="goods.php" method="post">
    good's name<br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="goods" <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn_select" value="select">
    <input type="submit" name="btn_insert" value="insert">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Евгений Шалаев, спасибо. Заработал. :)

Comment: Евгений Шалаев, закомментировал display: flex но ничего не меняется. В чём его необходимость?

Comment: @Delphi159 забыл удалить) сейчас исправлю